# How can I make buttons go closer to each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create welcome banner on my index page but ran into issue where I need the buttons to be closer to each other but cannot figure out a way to do that. The buttons should go to right and left to be closer but they are pushed out of each other with flex not with padding nor margin.

Here's my code :

```html
<section id="career">
<!--Welcome banner-->
    <div class="container-fluid height-51 career-picture d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="career-text">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="display-3 text-white text-center font-proximanovabold custom-font-size-header-title">Company</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="h5 text-white text-center font-proximanovalight custom-font-size-header-content">The biggest shipping company on earth</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-green text-white custom-font-size-header-button">ButtonOne</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-green text-white custom-font-size-header-button">ButtonTwo</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--End of welcome banner section-->
</section>
```

Here are my CSS edits that might somehow cause the problem :

```css
.height-51{
    min-height: 51.5vh;
}
.career-picture{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/career.jpg") center/cover no-repeat;
}
#career .btn{
    padding: 12px 24px !important;
}
```

How can I make the buttons to go closer to each other? Why are the pushed with "themselves" but not with margin/padding? Thanks to anyone.

Comment: If you replace `col-md-6` to `col-md-1` it would work: https://www.bootply.com/Uq7lsIvq1W `col-md-6` takes the 1/2 width of the whole row.

Comment: Yes but that pushes the buttons to the left. The buttons should be under the text.

Comment: Just made some markup changes: https://www.bootply.com/l7xZTYB8Bq

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks a lot you can post this as an answer so it will check as solved. What does 'bis_skin_checked="1"' exactly do? haven't seen that ever but it does the job perfectly!

Comment: Please ignore it. It was added by a browser extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the buttons in a new row and reduce the width of the columns i.e. from `col-md-6` to `col-md-2` so that it does not take 1/2 of the whole row which makes it go wider. Remove the padding applied.

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.height-51 {
  min-height: 51.5vh;
}

.career-picture {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/career.jpg") center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="career">
  <!--Welcome banner-->
  <div class="container-fluid height-51 career-picture d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="career-text">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="display-3 text-white text-center font-proximanovabold custom-font-size-header-title">Company</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="h5 text-white text-center font-proximanovalight custom-font-size-header-content">The biggest shipping company on earth</div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-green text-white custom-font-size-header-button">ButtonOne</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-green text-white custom-font-size-header-button">ButtonTwo</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End of welcome banner section-->
</section>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the button in the same div and span it 12 columns...

HTML

```
<section id="career">
<!--Welcome banner-->
    <div class="container-fluid height-51 career-picture d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="career-text">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="display-3 text-white text-center font-proximanovabold custom-font-size-header-title">Company</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="h5 text-white text-center font-proximanovalight custom-font-size-header-content">The biggest shipping company on earth</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-success text-white custom-font-size-header-button">ButtonOne</button>
                 <button class="btn btn-success text-white custom-font-size-header-button">ButtonTwo</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--End of welcome banner section-->
</section>
```

CSS

```
.height-51{
  min-height: 51.5vh;
  padding: 1em;
}
.career-picture {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/career.jpg") center/cover no-repeat;
}
#career .btn{
  padding: 12px 24px;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```